# show that $\sum_{j=1}^n|I_j|\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the set $E:=(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Let $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^n$ be a finite collection cover of $E$. I try to show that $\sum_{j=1}^n|I_j|\ge 1$.

---

My idea is that I try to show that $(0,1)\subset \cup_{j=1}^n \overline{I}_j$, where $\overline{I}_j$ is the closed interval of $I_j$ for $j=1,\dots, n$.

Question: I am not sure if we can assume that $(0,1)\subset \cup_{j=1}^n \overline{I}_j$ by closed intervals.

If this is not true, then there is a real number $x\in  (0,1)\setminus \cup_{j=1}^n \overline{I}_j$. Since $(0,1)\setminus \cup_{j=1}^n \overline{I}_j$ is non-empty open interval, then
$$
\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)\setminus \cup_{j=1}^n \overline{I}_j\neq \emptyset
$$
which is a contradiction with $$\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)\subset \cup_{j=1}^n \overline{I}_j$$

Hence,
$$
(0,1)\subset \cup_{j=1}^n I_j
$$

Then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n |I_j|\ge |\cup_{j=1}^n I_j|= |\cup_{j=1}^n \overline{I}_j|\ge 1
$$

Comment: Aiming for a contradiction, you should take $n+1$ points not covered by $n$ by intervals $\{I_i\}_{i=1}^n.$ Then, for such points $x_k,x_{k+1},$ consider the interval $J_k:=(x_k,x_{k+1})$ and choose a point in $y_k\in E\cap J_k.$ Since there are only $n$ intervals $I_i$ covering $E$ and $E\ni y_k$'s are covered, then some two of them must be in the same interval $I_{i_0}$ (by the pigeonhole principle) forcing some $x_{k'}$ to be in $I_{i_0}$ and therefore, in $E.$

Comment: @PinkyWay I do not understand why do we need to take $n+1$ points. There is one result that nonempty open set is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I applied this result to get the contradiction because there is must be a rational number in $(0,1)\setminus \cup I_i$... Does it make sense?

Comment: You should take $n+1$ points if your cover consists of $n$ intervals. And non-empty open set need not be dense in $\Bbb R$ are at all...

Comment: Once you show your cover doesn't contain at most finitely many points from $(0,1)$ (my first comment), proceed as follows: $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{i=1}^n|I_i|&\ge\lambda\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i\right)\\&\ge\lambda\left(\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n I_j\right)\cap(0,1)\right)\\&=\lambda((0,1))-\lambda\left(\underbrace{(0,1)\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i}_{\text{finite set}}\right)\\&=1-0\\&=1,\end{aligned}$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $((0,1),\mathcal L(0,1)).$